# Gallery stop working if one picture could not loaded

Tags: jquery, galleria

I am using galleria on my html webpage and everything works fine while all images are available (HTTP 200).

If one Image is not available (HTTP 404) the gallery gives me this error and is no longer usable. `Image not found: http://path...`.

How can galleria just ignore images which are not available or dont show the error message and just work with the ones which are successfully loaded?

It is reproduceable with the new version of [galleria](https://galleria.io/get-started/) and just change the url of one image:

```
 <a href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Athabasca_Rail_at_Brule_Lake.jpg/800px-Athabasca_Rail_at_Brule_Lake.jpg">
    <img 
         src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Athabasca_Rail_at_Brule_Lake.jpg/100px-Athabasca_Rail_at_Brule_Lake.jpg",
         data-big="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Athabasca_Rail_at_Brule_Lake.jpg/1280px-Athabasca_Rail_at_Brule_Lake.jpg"
         data-title="Athabasca Rail"
         data-description="The Athabasca River railroad track at the mouth of Brulé Lake in Alberta, Canada."
    >
</a>
```

Comment: Why don't you just make sure that the image URL exists? Is there any constraint that's stopping you to do this?

Comment: @HyderB. I have to create the html on backend site and just get some url from the DB. So at this time I dont know if they really exist. Thats a problem but I have to live with that for now.

Comment: are you using PHP for the backend?

Comment: @HyderB. no using PLSQL. and create HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the javascript of galleria its possible to set a dummy value. During debugging in error case the dummy value is used if its set.

```
internal constants
VERSION = 1.45,
DEBUG = true,
TIMEOUT = 30000,
DUMMY = 'dummy Image path',
```

And in the error case it is present in the gallery.

```
else {
 // apply the dummy image if it exists
  if ( DUMMY ) {
  $( this ).attr( 'src', DUMMY );
  } else {
  Galleria.raise('Image not found: ' + src);
  }
```